# Optimizing Google Apps Script nested loops

Tags: for-loop, optimization, google-apps-script

is there a way to remove the for loops or to make them more efficient?

Here is my case:

I have a Google Spreadsheet that uses the following Google Apps Script function 6 times:

```
  var factor_r = [];
  var apr_r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(apr).getValues();
  var num_installments_r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(num_installments).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < apr_r.length; i++) {
    factor_r[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < apr_r[i].length; j++) {
      var factor = 1;
      var apr_factor = 1.0 + apr_r[i][j];
      var time_fraction = 0.0;
      for(var k = 1; k < num_installments_r[0][j]; k++) {
        time_fraction = (15+30.5*k)/365;
        factor += 1/Math.pow(apr_factor, time_fraction);
      }
      factor_r[i][j] = factor;
    }
  }
  return factor_r;
};
```

The `apr` input variable is a range matrix of 24x90 and `num_installments` is an array of 24. Each of this runs takes few minutes and the inputs impact in other cells that have formulas that also take some time. Overall it turns that loading my spreadsheet takes up to 15-20 minutes. It may not seem much but is something we need to share externally and would like to improve it. I think if the code above can be optimised the overall loading time of the spreadsheet can go down significantly.

Any ideas on how to do so?

Thank you,
Clara

Comment: Do you really need to do this every single time you open the sheet? If not you could set up a button to trigger this specific, and isolated, function and you would save 5 runs.

Comment: Hi Kessy, thank you for your answer.The truth is that I don't need to do it every time I open the sheet at all. Google Sheets does it by itself. I tried to find a way for "manually" calculations only but couldn't find so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a button to run the script only when you need it.
To create a button on sheets:

1. Go to Insert -> Drawing
2. Draw the shape you want and insert some text in it.
3. Once you have it on your sheet -> right click on the button (you will see 3 points on the right top) -> Assign Script -> assign the function you want that button to run like *myFunction*.

**I strongly recommend to isolate this function if your script does more things, so with this button you will run this specific function**

Comment: Thank you, will try that. Need to see how it will work with different inputs, but seems a great solution. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, if you find the answer useful, please accept it so others can use it as well